# Node.js Javascript program exiting without waiting for input from user

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to javascript and having some issues getting my code to keep asking for user input until they ask to quit. It runs once, prints the prompt again and then quits. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks! I know the actual conversion of infix to postfix isn't working at the moment either...

```
//RPN
var readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});
var presedence = {'POW': 0, '*': 1, '/': 1, '%': 1, '+': 2, '-': 2};
var operators = ['P', '*', '/', '%', '+', '-'];
var digits = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];

var convertInfix = function (infixQ) {
  //PEMDAS
  var opS = [];
  var postfixQ = [];
  var t;
  while (infixQ.length != 0) {
    t = infixQ.shift();
    console.log(t)
    console.log(typeof t)
    if (digits.indexOf(t) > -1) {
      console.log('push number')
      postfixQ.push(t);
    }
    else if (opS.length === 0 || t == '(') {
      console.log('push operator')
      opS.push(t);
    }
    else if (t == ')') {
      while (opS[0] != '(') {
        opS.Push(t);
      }
    }
    else {
      while (opS.length != 0 && opS[0] != '(') {
        if (presedence[t] > presedence[opS[0]]) {
          break;
        }
        postfixQ.push(opS[0]);
        opS.pop();
        console.log

      }
    }
  }
  while (opS.length != 0) {
    postfixQ.push(opS[0]);
    opS.pop();
  }
  console.log(postfixQ)
};

var main = function () {
  rl.question('Enter an infix expression or "quit" to exit the     program:', (rawInfix) => {
    if (rawInfix == 'quit') {
      console.log('Exiting')
      return;
    } else {
      var infixQ = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < rawInfix.length; i++) {
        if (digits.indexOf(raxInfix[i]) > -1 ||
          operators.indexOf(rawInfix[i]) > -1 ||
          rawInfix[i] == ' ') {
          infixQ.push(rawInfix[i])
        } else if (rawInfix[i] != 'W' || rawInfix[i] != 'O') {
          console.log('Unexpected Character in input: ', rawInfix)
          main()
        }
      }
      postfixQ = convertInfix(infixQ)
      main()
      // evaluatePostFix(postfixQ)
    }
    rl.close();
  });
}
main();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.  Commented out the code that doesn't yet work.  Recursively called main if user does not enter 'quit'.  Close readline if they do.

```
//RPN
 var readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface({
input: process.stdin,
output: process.stdout
});
var presedence = {'POW':0,'*':1,'/':1,'%':1,'+':2,'-':2 };
var operators = ['P','*','/','%','+','-'];
var digits = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];

var convertInfix= function(infixQ){
  //PEMDAS
   var opS =[];
   var postfixQ =[];
   var t;
   while (infixQ.length != 0){
 t = infixQ.shift();
 console.log(t)
 console.log(typeof t)
 if (digits.indexOf(t)>-1){
     console.log('push number')
     postfixQ.push(t);
   }
 else if (opS.length === 0 || t=='('){
     console.log('push operator')
     opS.push(t);
   }
 else if (t ==')'){
   while (opS[0] !='('){
      opS.Push(t);
    }
  }
  else {
     while(opS.length != 0 && opS[0] != '('){
     if (presedence[t]>presedence[opS[0]]){
       break;
      }
     postfixQ.push(opS[0]);
     opS.pop();
     console.log

   }
 }
 }while(opS.length != 0){
 postfixQ.push(opS[0]);
 opS.pop();
 }
 console.log(postfixQ)
};

var main =function(){
  rl.question('Enter an infix expression or "quit" to exit the     
program:',(rawInfix) =>{
  if (rawInfix == 'quit'){
    console.log('Exiting')
    rl.close();
    return;
  }else{
      console.log(rawInfix);
      main();
// var infixQ= [];
// for(var i=0;i<rawInfix.length;i++){
//   if (digits.indexOf(raxInfix[i])>-1 ||
//       operators.indexOf(rawInfix[i])>-1 ||
//       rawInfix[i]==' '){
//     infixQ.push(rawInfix[i])
//   }else if (rawInfix[i]!='W' || rawInfix[i]!='O'){
//     console.log('Unexpected Character in input: ',rawInfix)
//     main()
//   }
// }
// postfixQ = convertInfix(infixQ)
// main()
// // evaluatePostFix(postfixQ)
  }

});
}
   main();
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you should read some articles about Node.js. A special feature of Node.js is that I/O operations are handled asynchronously: [Node.js - Callbacks Concept](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_callbacks_concept.htm)

Your program quits because the prompt input is handled asynchrone in your code. If you want to do some inputs in your prompt I would recommend using existing node packages. This one worked very well for me in the past: [prompt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompt)

Comment: EDIT: I have replaced the link of the article with a better one in my answer. This one is much easier to understand and you haven't got to read so much ;-)